# Python not importing GETCH

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, getch

I have installed (Through PIP/The Terminal) GETCH yet python will not recognize it when I tell it to

```
import getch
```

I am on a Mac

```
sudo pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/getch/getch-1.0-python2.tar.gz#md5=586ea0f1f16aa094ff6a30736ba03c50
The directory '/Users/aaronoliver/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/aaronoliver/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/getch/getch-1.0-python2.tar.gz#md5=586ea0f1f16aa094ff6a30736ba03c50
Downloading getch-1.0-python2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): getch==1.0 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/g/getch/getch-1.0-python2.tar.gz#md5=586ea0f1f16aa094ff6a30736ba03c50 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: What does `pip list` show? What does "not recognize" mean? `ImportError`? Something else?

Comment: Not recognize that it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this question 3.x, but your evidence that `getch` is installed clearly indicates it's installed in the `site-packages` for 2.7. You also provided `pip` an explicit path to a Python 2 tarball.

Installing a package for one version of Python doesn't install it for other versions. Run `pip3` to install packages for Python 3 (it may be named `pip-3.5` or the like, depending on setup). If `pip3` is not installed, `python3 -mensurepip` should add it (depending on Python minor version), or you'll have to install it manually. Either way, once you have `pip3`, you just need to install the package correctly:

```
sudo pip3 install getch
```

Comment: Whoops, didn't realize what I was doing when I did it